# Script to monitor any modifications in files in my FTP site

Tags: bash, curl, ftp, wc

Iam trying to build a script to monitor any modifications in files in my FTP site. The script is given below. I have used `wc -l` to count the no. of files in the directory and have defined the constant value of files if there is going to be any modification in files like if my co-worker updates in my FTP this will send me a notification. Am trying to cron this to achieve. But the script actually just hangs after the count . It doesn't provide me the expected result. Is there anything that am wrong with the code. Am just a beginner in Bash could anyone help me solve this

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
curl ftp://Sterst:abh89TbuOc@############################/Test/| wc -l ;
read b;
a=9
if [ "$b" != "$a" ];
then 
echo  "FTP dir has modified mail" -s "dir notification" sni912@######.com;
fi
```

Comment: try to use inotify-tools on ftp server

Comment: iwatch command am not able to do it for an FTP. Is there any way?

Comment: https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki

Comment: Do you have shell access to the FTP server, or do you only have FTP access?

Comment: hi, Glenn Jackman ,i have only FTP access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes about your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
curl ftp://Sterst:abh89TbuOc@############################/Test/| wc -l ;
read b;
```

That does not do what you think it does: the `wc` output goes to stdout, not into the `read` command. Do this instead:  `b=$( curl ... | wc -l )`

```
a=9
if [ "$b" != "$a" ];
```

Since the `wc` output will have some extra whitespace, better to do a numeric comparison:
`if (( a != b ))`

```
then 
echo  "FTP dir has modified mail" -s "dir notification" sni912@######.com;
```

You probably mean this:

```
echo  "FTP dir has modified" | mail -s "dir notification" sni912@######.com;
```

I would write this:

```
listing=$( curl ftp://... )
num=$( echo "$listing" | wc -l )
if (( num != 9 )); then
    mail -s "ftp dir modification" email@example.com <<END
FTP directory modification

$listing
END
fi
```

Comment: I was unaware that curl would return a listing for `ftp://host/directory/`, that's pretty cool.

Comment: hi glenn, i didn't try the suggestions provided by you yet but on the first look it is superrvv thanks a lott will post once trying the same

Comment: am getting the below error                                                                    Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")

Comment: did you forget a semicolon, or the "then"?

Comment: still am finding it difficult am getting the below error.    
testnew.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
testnew.sh: line 6: `fi'

Comment: that was cause of some formatting prob i guess it worked after dos2unix but still have a different prob 
testnew.sh: 4: testnew.sh: num: not found

Comment: The mail command is waiting for you to type the body of the email and press Ctrl-D

Answer (score 0):

My code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
listing=$( curl  ftp://username:password@ftp.com/test/ )
num=$( wc -l | echo "$listing" )
if (( num != 9 ));
then
mail -s "ftp dir modification" email@example.com
fi `
```

Comment: what if i have to do this for multiple ftp links i tried curling multiple links and if looping them in  a single bash file but am getting an error `test.sh: 31: not found